I am trying to connect a series of Beckhoff modules via CODESYS using an Ethernet port


As mentioned in the title, I need to run CODESYS locally on Windows 10 and try to find a series of Beckhoff modules connected to an Ethernet port.
I am not sure if I need to download any additional drivers or other software
I have read many guides on this topic, but nothing seems to work. I have two Ethernet ports,Realtek PCI GbE Family Controller and Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM, and I read that I need to activate promiscuous mode by installing Npcap, but I haven't had any results. I have also added Component.1=CmpSysEthernet to the CODESYS path. I am attaching two screenshots of the CODESYS project with the EtherCAT master.


